# Why do properties modified by @optional become immutable?

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-swift-bridge, objective-c-protocol

I have an **Objective-C** protocol that contains a property as follows:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol Playback <NSObject>

@optional

@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSURL *assetURL;

@end
```

`PlayerController` has a property of type `id<Playback>`:

```objectivec
@interface PlayerController: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) id<Playback> currentPlayerManager;

@end
```

I tried to write the following code in **Swift**, but I got an **error**:

```swift
var player = PlayerController()
var pla = player.currentPlayerManager

pla.assetURL = URL(string: "123") // ❌ Cannot assign to property: 'pla' is immutable
```

If I comment out the `@optional` for the `Playback`  protocol, then it compiles fine.

This makes me wonder why `@optional` would cause this error?

Comment: This may actually be worth asking over on the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/), where you may get someone who works on the compiler to chime in. This seems very much to be an extremely niche edge case whose compiler diagnostic is also not particularly helpful; it may be a bug that this does not compile (this does work in Obj-C), or at least the message can be refined. FWIW, you can define the exact same protocol + properties in pure Swift (with the `@objc` annotation to allow for an `optional var`) and you'll see the same behavior.

Comment: Another issue is that you have a type mismatch between URL and NSURL.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I would also like to ask a question on the Swift forum, but unfortunately, for some objective reason, I can't access this site...

Comment: @Rakuyo That's unfortunate. :( I would be more than happy to post on your behalf there, but I'm afraid you wouldn't be able to view the responses...

Comment: @ItaiFerber If you can help me that would be really appreciated, you can send me an email when you have a definite conclusion or reply to me under this question. This may take some of your time, but if you don't have time then just ask me instead, as long as the question helps more people I'll be happy.

Comment: @Rakuyo Absolutely. I'll ask on the forums and relay a (hopefully definitive) response here.

Comment: For anyone curious in following along with access to the forums, posted the question here: https://forums.swift.org/t/compilation-error-in-assigning-to-obj-c-optional-protocol-property/53886

Comment: It's a known bug. See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5475 where Jordan Rose also gives an excellent workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jordan Rose (who worked on Swift at the time that [SE-0070](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0070-optional-requirements.md) was implemented) [on the forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/compilation-error-in-assigning-to-obj-c-optional-protocol-property/53886/2):

> Normally optional requirements add an extra level of optionality:
>
> - Methods become optional themselves (`f.bar?()`)
> - Property getters wrap the value in an extra level of `Optional` (`if let bar = f.bar`)
>
> But there's nowhere to put that extra level of Optional for a property setter. That's really the entire story: we never figured out how to expose optional property setters in a safe way, and didn't want to pick any particular unsafe solution. If someone can think of something that'd be great!

So the answer appears to be: at the time that `optional` protocol requirements were intentionally limited to Objective-C protocols in Swift ([SE-0070](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0070-optional-requirements.md)), no spelling for an explicit implementation of this was decided on, and it appears that this functionality is uncommon enough that this hasn't really come up since.

Until (and if) this is supported, there are two potential workarounds:

1. Introduce an explicit method to `Playback` which assigns a value to `assetURL`

   - Sadly, this method cannot be named `-setAssetURL:` because it will be imported into Swift as if it were the property setter instead of a method, and you still won't be able to call it. (This is still true if you mark `assetURL` as `readonly`)
   - Also sadly, this method won't be able to have a default implementation, since Objective-C doesn't support default protocol implementations, and you can't give the method an implementation in a Swift `extension` because you still can't assign to the protocol
2. Do like you would in Swift and introduce a protocol *hierarchy*, where, for example, an `AssetBackedPlayback` protocol inherits from `Playback` and offers `assetURL` as a non-`@optional`-property instead:

   ```
   @protocol Playback <NSObject>
   // Playback methods
   @end

   @protocol AssetBackedPlayback: Playback
   @property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSURL *assetURL;
   @end
   ```

   You would then need to find a way to expose `PlayerController.currentPlayerManager` as an `AssetBackedPlayback` in order to assign the `assetURL`.

---

Some additional alternatives from Jordan:

> I think the original recommended workaround was "write a `static inline` function in Objective-C to do it for you", but that's not wonderful either. `setValue(_:forKey:)` can also be good enough in practice if it's not in a hot path.

The `static inline` function recommendation can function similarly to a default protocol implementation, but you do need to remember to call that function instead of accessing the property directly.

`setValue(_:forKey:)` will also work, but incurs a noticeable performance penalty because it supports a lot of dynamism through the Objective-C runtime, and is significantly more complicated than a simple assignment. Depending on your use-case, the cost may be acceptable in order to avoid complexity!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's optional, Swift can't guarantee the setter is implemented.

Comment: So why does it not report an error when I try to get the value from it? The getter method must exist? Why?

Comment: Retrieving the value can return an optional. It need not exist.

Comment: I don't disagree with the reasoning, but theoretically, a setter could also be implemented in the same way that `optional` methods are implemented: if the setter does not exist, the operation is a no-op. I would still be curious about more authoritative reasoning — I don't think this is really documented anywhere, but again, it may be worth prodding on the Swift Forums (or digging through the compiler).